# How can I get a list of currencies from Wikidata?

Tags: data-request, finance, wikidata

Some currencies already exist, like [1], [2] and they are all instances of `currency` [3]. Unfortunately there are no links to all instances from [3].
So is there a possibility to get this list from Wikidata?

- [1]    http://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q4916 (Euro)
- [2]    http://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q4917 (US dollar)
- [3]    http://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q8142 (Currency)

Comment: [In SPARQL](https://query.wikidata.org/#select%20distinct%20%3Fc%20%3FcLabel%20%20%7B%3Fc%20wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%2a%20wd%3AQ8142%20service%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20%7D%7D)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is.

There are several ways to get this list:

1. You can, in Wikidata website, look at every entity that has a link to currency (`Q8142`): https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:WhatLinksHere/Q8142. The problem of this is that you will have some entities that makes a link to currency other than `instance of`.
2. The best way is to use an external tool called AutoList, developed by a German guy called [Magnus Manske](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Magnus_Manske). The link of his tool is here:
   https://tools.wmflabs.org/autolist/autolist1.html

This tool uses a query language WDQ. Its documentation is here:
https://wdq.wmflabs.org/api_documentation.html

Here is how it works:

The property "instance of" has the identifier `P31`.
The value "currency" has the identifier `Q8142`.

If you want every Wikidata entity with the condition `(P31 == Q8142)` equals true:

- copy-paste `claim[31:8142]` in the form field called Query;
- click on the Run button.

Comment: You can also use [this link](https://tools.wmflabs.org/autolist/?wdq=claim%5B31%3A8142%5D&run) which brings you directly to the results.

Answer (score 2):

The official dataset on currencies is maintained by the ISO 4217 standard. You can download the currency dataset in XML or Excel format at this link:

http://www.currency-iso.org/en/home/tables/table-a1.html

Comment: I'm aware of that but specifically want this information from wikidata and I know it's in there, I just don't know how to access it.