# Machine readable list of monetary currencies, including symbol

Tags: data-request, finance, programming

Does someone know a machine readable currency list, that includes the symbol?

For example

```
Aruba Guilder,AWG,ƒ,ƒ
Australia Dollar,AUD,$,$
```

I've found various sources, but they either lack the symbol (e.g $)

- https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/3984/1511 (although perhaps I don't know enough about how to use Wikidata to find the symbol)
- http://www.currency-iso.org/en/home/tables/table-a1.html
- https://github.com/datasets/currency-codes/blob/master/data/codes-all.csv

Or the lack the machine readability (would require scraping)

- http://www.xe.com/symbols.php

---

(I've added a self-answer with the few resources that I've found.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least three github repos

- [Currency-List](https://github.com/umpirsky/currency-list) - many formats - "List of all currencies with names and ISO 4217 codes in all languages and all data formats."
- [JSON](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Fluidbyte/2973986/raw/b0d1722b04b0a737aade2ce6e055263625a0b435/Common-Currency.json) (gist) - (I'll use this one for now)
- [YAML](https://github.com/hexorx/currencies/blob/master/lib/data/iso4217.yaml) or [gem](https://github.com/hexorx/currencies) - "It contains every currency in the ISO 4217 standard"