# Open database of historical currency holidays for major currency pairs

Tags: data-request

Is there a database containing all **historical** currency holidays for the major currency pairs ?

It would be in the spirit of the following data (https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=709), but historical (since 1995 at least).

Comment: Possible duplicate. See answers here: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/7418/machine-readable-list-of-monetary-currencies-including-symbol

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a free reuters link, but this is only for few currencies and only since 2013. You can try this - https://dxtra.markets.reuters.com/Dx/DxnOutbound/400201801100745208295001.htm

Comment: This link is dead.

Answer (score -3):

I didn't find a proper open source, but one can use the calendars from a Bloomberg terminal.